# How to put the right border of a View onto horizontal center?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

In my Android app, I am using a `RelativeLayout` to custom one of my `Activity`s.
I have a square `ImageView` that I want to set precisely. In other words, I want its right border to touch the horizontal center of the layout.

Is such a thing possible without doing weird things such as centering and then marging?

Answer (score 2):

It's not a perfect solution but potentially you could use:
android:layout_marginRight="xdp"
Where x is half of your screen width + half the width of your imageView?
I know it's not perfect but might help until some guru comes along

Comment: Like you say it's a good workaround until someone comes up with a better solution.